# How do you enable a checkboxradio with JQuery-ui that was initialized as disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a checkbox that I need to have enabled and disabled when another action happens on the page.
The checkbox is altered using jquery-ui and thus it looks pretty.
Here is the pseudo code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openchest").checkboxradio();
    $("#enablebutton").click(function(){
        $("#openchest").prop("disabled", false); // Doesnt work
        $("#openchest").checkboxradio("enable"); // Also doesn't work
    });
});
</script>
<button id="enablebutton">enable checkbox</button>
<label for="openchest">Open Chest</label><input type="checkbox" id="openchest" disabled="disabled" value="1" />
```

What do I need to change to make the button re-enable the checkbox initialized by jquery-ui?

Comment: Your code appears to work...

Comment: @David The reason why it appears to work is due to 2 reasons: 
1. because I made a mistake on my dummy code, having an empty label 
2. testing it here does not initialize JQuery-UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the documentation intending to destroy and re-initialize the widget, I discovered that you need to add refresh to the widget.

`Refresh()`

`Refreshes the visual state of the widget. Useful for updating after the native element's checked or disabled state is changed programmatically.`

Here is the correct code that works:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openchest").checkboxradio();
    $("#enablebutton").click(function(){
        $("#openchest").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#openchest").checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
});
</script>
<button id="enablebutton">enable checkbox</button>
<label for="openchest">Open Chest</label><input type="checkbox" id="openchest" disabled="disabled" value="1" />
```